# Why is it that when I try to copy over a photo into InDesign, its just a filled white box?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been trying to place an image in InDesign and it becomes a white box.  Also when I just drag the photo over (as is) it still does the same.  Does this have something to do with the file?[image: When I drag the Photo into InDesign]

Comment: To see what happens, try to place a different picture first  and if that still doesn't work, try placing it into a new document.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the white box is empty in above image so:

1. Click the white box to select
2. Hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and a window will appear to place the image
3. Select your image

If you get the image out of place then:

1. Select the box and right click
2. Click *Fitting > Fill Frame Proportionally*, or
3. When hovering mouse over white box, you can click the circle, hold and drag up/down/left/right